# How to send the data from view to the some other specified controller's action in zend?

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have problem while navigating to desired controller action using anchor href,href includes the params also to send values.
Tried with the rendering  and static ways to fixing the path, but need to ticket So how do I get the controller ...?

code:

```
echo $this->url(array('action'=>'documentshow','folder_id'=>$fid,doc_id'=>$doc_id),null,true);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand.
But in your example, it lacks a quote before **'** doc_id'

```
echo $this->url (array ('action' => 'documentshow', 'folder_id' => $fid, 'doc_id '=> $ doc_id), null, true);
```

Otherwise you can try this:

```
$helperUrl = new Zend_View_Helper_Url();
$url = "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] 
                 . $helperUrl->url(array('action'     => 'documentshow', 
                                         'controller' => 'your_controller',
                                         'folder_id'  => $fid,
                                         'doc_id'     => $doc_id
                                   ));
```

I hope it will help you :)

Comment: Happy for you. Good Luck